# plotting symfun and a self created function on same graph matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

i am trying to plot two function in matlab, the first one is of kinf symfun:

```
p = symfun(0, [m]);
p(m) = p(m)+Ck(k-3)*exp(m*(k-3)*complex(0, 2*pi/25));
```

here Ck is another symfun and k is a variable i pre-defined.

i want to plot it in the same graph with a function i created using the function mode:

```
function [x1] = xt_otot_q3( t)...
```

i cant make the xt_otot_q3 function a symfun because it involves if statements.
- i tried to create 2 vectors sampling the two functions and plotting them together with the plot function but for some reason the 'p' function vectors gets preatty grotesque giving me wierd output... 
- i tried plotting them both using ezplot function but for some reason the sampled vector i got form xt_otot_q3 shows only as a straight line at 0.

any ideas how i should plot them together? to plot the xt_otot_q3 function i must create a vector if i try to plot it directly using ezplot it gives me the following eror:

```
>> ezplot(xt_otot_q3, [-10 10])
Error using xt_otot_q3 (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it properly, you have two functions p, and xt_otot_q3. You want to plot them together.

```
syms t;
func1 = xt_otot_q3(t);
ezplot(func1, [-10 10]); 
# retain current graph, for new graph
hold on;
# symbolic function p
ezplot(p, [-10 10]);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: hi, it doesnt work, i tried it already, it gives me the following error after line 2: `Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.` its because i have an if statement inside of it.

Comment: each place where formula refers to t, you want the substitution of numeric values to take place, you need to instead 
   **code.double(subs(t))**. This is done to substitute symbolic variable by its numeric value.

Comment: what do you mean? can you please put it inside the code? here is a peace of the code in the function: `if abs(t)<= 8 
    x1 = exp(-abs(t));`

Comment: `abs(double(subs(t)))<= 8 x1 = exp(-abs(double(subs(C))));`